# Android AdMob Adaptive banner in Fragment on kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, banner

Official documentation `Adaptive Banner` only about the activity. If I try to apply this to a Fragment, I get `Unresolved reference: windowManager`. If I'm trying to add a `WindowManager interface` to my Fragment, then I need to override 5 methods that I don't know what to do with. `addView(), updateViewLayout(), removeView(), getDefaultDisplay(), removeViewImmidiate()`. Does anyone have a ready example of how to add an Adaptive Banner to a Fragment?

```
private val adSize: AdSize
get() {
  val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
  val outMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
  display.getMetrics(outMetrics)

  val density = outMetrics.density

  var adWidthPixels = ad_view_container.width.toFloat()
  if (adWidthPixels == 0f) {
    adWidthPixels = outMetrics.widthPixels.toFloat()
  }

  val adWidth = (adWidthPixels / density).toInt()
  return AdSize.getCurrentOrientationBannerAdSizeWithWidth(this, adWidth)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I setup the main activity similar to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/adaptive), with some small changes:

1. Put the `adView` variable in a companion object so it can be accessed by a fragment
2. Moved `ad_view_container.addView(adView)` from `onCreate` of the activity, to `onViewCreated` of a fragment that holds the `ad_view_container`
3. Removed the check for the ad view container width (`ad_view_container.width.toFloat()`) from the activity, as the `ad_view_container` is now located within the fragment. Hence, the full screen width must be used for the ad. Maybe there is some way to get the `ad_view_container`'s width from the fragment but for me this wasn't necessary as I wanted a full width ad.

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  
  companion object {
    lateinit var adView: AdView
  }

  // Set the ad size to the full screen width.
  private val adSize: AdSize
    get() {
      val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
      val outMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
      display.getMetrics(outMetrics)

      val density = outMetrics.density

      val adWidthPixels = outMetrics.widthPixels.toFloat()

      val adWidth = (adWidthPixels / density).toInt()
      return AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(this, adWidth)
    }

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my)

    // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
    MobileAds.initialize(this) { }

    adView = AdView(this)
    loadBanner()
  }

  private fun loadBanner() {
    adView.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" //TODO - change
    adView.adSize = adSize

    // Create an ad request.
    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest)
  }

}
```

Fragment:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Add the adaptive banner to its container
        ad_view_container.addView(adView)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()

        // Remove the adaptive banner from its container
        adViewContainer.removeAllViews()
    }

}
```

And of course the `ad_view_container` in the fragment layout xml file:

```
...

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_view_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

...
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpON9.png)

Comment: How woudl you setup the ads if you wanted inline with a recylerview in a fragment!?